# Postgres - Transfer Database From Local Machine to Hosting Machine (PythonAnywhere)

Tags: postgresql, wagtail, pythonanywhere

I am deploying a Wagtail site on PythonAnywhere with a Postgres database.I had a small test site and database that I created using the wagtail example [here](https://github.com/texperience/wagtail-pythonanywhere-quickstart) and the postgres example [here](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/PostgresGettingStarted/).

Once I verified that worked, I uploaded my project files in a new directory and decided to reuse the database and run pg_restore to update it. I used `--clean` to make sure it dropped and replaced any tables.

```
pg_restore --clean -h user-xxxx.postgres.pythonanywhere-services.com -p <port> -d <dbname> -U <username_created_in_example> /path/to/backup
```

However, when I checked one of the tables, they were not updated. Example, I checked wagtailcore_pages and it still had two entries from the test site rather than the 200+ entries from my backup.

When I checked the pg_restore output, there were a lot of errors. The primary ones were:

```
ERROR:  must be owner of table...
ERROR:  permission denied for table...
ERROR:  must be owner of sequence...
ERROR:  relation "<name_of_something>" already exists
ERROR:  constraint "<name_of_something>" does not exist
```

So I think the reason I'm not seeing fully populated tables is because of all these errors and the backup queries from the backup file are not executing. So to fix them, I tried the commands below:

**Attempt #1:**
On my local machine where I created the backup, the user was "userLocal". So when I created a user with the same name on the PythonAnywhere postgres db, and then used that user in pg_restore command. That made some "userLocal user does not exist" errors go away, but did not solve the problems above.

Note: Not sure if just creating a user with the same name is enough? On my local machine, I think my user has more permissions.

**Attempt #2:**
I ran pg_restore with `--no-owner`

```
pg_restore --clean --no-owner -h user-xxxx.postgres.pythonanywhere-services.com -p <port> -d <dbname> -U <username_that_matches_name_in_backup> /path/to/backup
```

Still getting "must be owner" errors.

**Attempt #3:**
Change the database ownership using `ALTER DATABASE name OWNER TO new_owner;`
Still getting "must be owner" errors.

Does anyone know what I could be doing wrong? Am I right in thinking that the tables are not populating because of the errors? Is there a different approach I should be following to get my database from my local machine to the web based system?

Also, I don't think I have access to anything sudo/super related on PythonAnywhere. So any suggestions leaning away from that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Django’s [`dumpdata`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata) command to export your data to a JSON file. Upload that to your production setup and use the `loaddata` command for the import. It is as simple as

```
python manage.py dumpdata --natural-foreign --indent 2 \
    -e contenttypes -e auth.permission -e postgres_search.indexentry \
    -e wagtailcore.groupcollectionpermission \
    -e wagtailcore.grouppagepermission -e wagtailimages.rendition \
    -e sessions > data.json

python manage.py loaddata data.json
```

Michael Yin wrote [a detailed tutorial on that](https://www.accordbox.com/blog/how-export-restore-wagtail-site/). The code above is taken from that. This has always worked perfectly for me.